Can anyone make me understand the payback to victim in judgement day?
Say a person steals some of a persons goods, murders a person, commits adultery while being married, stains ones honours wrongly, rapes someone etc.
Now that person repents to Allah sincerely, then will he/she be responsible or accountable to the victim on the day of judgement?

Whoever wrongs someone in any way, whether in terms of his honor, wealth, or anything else, let him make amends for it before the Day when there will be no dinar or dirham (currency), and if he has no good deeds, then some of the wronged person's bad deeds will be taken and added to his load(Bukhari).

So please help me understand in such situation will the victims rights be given respect in the hereafter if the criminal does not seek forgiveness of the victim in this world?

Any discussion or leads in comments are also appreciated

"Sorry" or repenting can be seen as a gesture of them realizing the truth but still everyone has to settle their Karma and only then they can rise to a higher consciousness. For some, Karma is already working through health, financial, personal and other issues. If they are facing so much trouble now, it's good so that they can easily get to the spirit world during Judgement Day.
